# Extracting and restricting time from the date object in a textbox

Tags: validation, date, object, time, restriction

I have searched everywhere but cannot find an answer for this particular question that I have. 
I'm making a pizza ordering website and instead of having a simple drop-down option for the time of pick-up or delivery field, we are required to have a text field so that the customer can manually enter the time themselves. I then need to validate the value of time by using DATE object to make sure it is between 6am and 11pm. Time must include am or pm.
Here is what I have so far:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Pizza Form
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <script>
    //Creating the function to extract the time
    function getTime() {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setHours();
        document.getElementById("pickTime").innerHTML = d;
    }

    }

    </script>
        <h1>Pizza Order Form</h1>
        <form>
            <fieldset><Legend>Is this for delivery or carryout?</legend>
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="DoC"               id="forDelivery">Delivery <font color="red" size="1.px">extra 30% of total</font></input></td>
                <td><input type="radio"name="DoC" id="forCarry">Carryout</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Delivery/Pickup Time</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="pickTime" value= "" onkeypress="return getTime()"> <font color="red" size="1.px" >Time should be between 6am and 11pm</font></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset><legend>Customer Info</legend>

        <table >
            <tr>
                <td>First and Last Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="flname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Address<br/ ><font color="red" size="1.px" id="address">Not required if takeout</font></td>
                <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="address"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone Number</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="phonenumber"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email Address</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="email"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset><legend>Choose Size and Crust</legend>
            <table style="width:100%" >
                <tr>
                    <th align="left">Hand Tossed</th>
                    <th align="left">Handmade Pan</th>
                    <th align="left">Crunchy Thin crust</th>
                    <th align="left">Brooklyn Style</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio"name="type" id="SHT" value="8">Small (10"-$8)</td>
                    <td><input type="radio"name="type" id="MHP" value"10">Medium (12"-$10)</td>
                    <td><input type="radio"name="type" id="MCTC" value="10">Medium (12"-$10)</td>
                    <td><input type="radio"name="type" id="LBS" value="13">Large (14"-13$)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio"name="type" id="MHT" value="9">Medium (12"-$9)</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="radio"name="type" id="LCTC" value="12">Large (14"-$12)</td>
                    <td><input type="radio"name="type" id="XLBS" value="15">X-Large (16"-$15)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio"name="type" id="LHT" value="10">Large (14"-$10)</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio"name="type" id="XLHT" value="11">X-Large (16"-$11)</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset><legend> Choose Cheese & Sauce</legend>
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td width="58%">Cheese?</td>
                <td>Sauce?</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select size="6">
                        <option id="nocheese" value="0">No Cheese</option>
                        <option id="lightcheese" value="1">Light - $1.00</option>
                        <option id="normalcheese" value="1.25">Normal - $1.25</option>
                        <option id="extracheese" value="1.5">Extra - $1.50</option>
                        <option id="dblcheese" value="1.75">Double - $1.75</option>
                        <option id="tplcheese" value="2">Triple - $2.00</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <select size="4">
                        <option id="nosauce" value="0">No Sauce</option>
                        <option id="lightsauce" value="0.5">Light - $0.50</option>
                        <option id="normalsauce" value="1">Normal - $1.00</option>
                        <option id="extrasauce" value="1.5">Extra - $1.50</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset><legend> Toppings (You can choose more than one - $2 each)</legend>
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td width="50%"
                ><input type="checkbox" id="pepporoni" value="2">Pepporoni</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="blackolive" value="2">Black Olives</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="mushroom" value="2">Mushrooms</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="greenpepper" value="2">Green Peppers</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="onions" value="2">Onions</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox">Pineapple</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="sausage" value="2">Sausage</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="spinach" value="2">Spinach</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="bacon" value="2">Bacon</td>

        </table>
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

[Here's what the website looks like so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq3ib.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5 you can use a `time` input, like this:

```
<INPUT id="MyId" name="MyName" type="time">
```

[More information on HTML5 input types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp).

If you are not using HTML5, you'll have to write a bit of script, or use one of many [jquery time picker plugins](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/) available freely.

Comment: I did that at first, but he said that format wasn't allowed. He wants the customers to literally be able to type in "11:18 AM" and have it validated with some sort of if statement using the date object.